# Analyzing the domain of this multi variable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Given the function: $f(x,y,z)= \frac{\sqrt {\ln{(1+z^2)}}}{|x|+|y|+ \sqrt{xy-1}}$ 
> Let $D$ be the maximal domain of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
> Find out whether $D$ is Open, Closed, Bounded, Connected domain.

It's my first time facing these types of questions with multi variable functions and here's what I did: 
Since the $ln$ will always be $\ge 0$ then I have no problem with it. 
but $xy-1\ge 0$ is a must, and $|x|+|y|+\sqrt{xy-1}>0$ also is a must (it's $\ne 0$ but since it's always positive I wrote it with $>$) 

Now to solve the question, I can say that it's not closed and not open domain since we have $\ge$ and $>$, but that's purely based on intuition, I tried to visualize the domain but I just couldn't, the furthest I reached was to write $y\ge \frac{1}{x}$ and try to visualize that part but it also was hard. 
I would appreciate any help and tips about how to deal with this question, thanks in advance!

Comment: Lookup equilateral hyperbola.

Comment: $|x|+|y|+\sqrt{xy-1}$ will always be greater than zero, so long as $\sqrt{xy-1}$ is real.     The only restriction is $xy-1 \ge 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$\;xy-1\ge0\implies xy\ge1\implies\begin{cases}y\ge\cfrac1x,&x>0\\{}\\y\le\cfrac1x ,&x<0\end{cases}$$

so your domain of definition is all the red and blue zones in the following graph:

[image]

Now you try to decide whether the above domain is open/closed/connected and etc,

Comment: Thanks alot for the help and the graph it really helped me visualize the domain, but shouldn't it be $\ge$ instead of $>$, or I'm missing something?

Comment: That's right, it can be $\;\ge\;$ and thus you must add the graph of $\;y=\cfrac1x\;$ , i.e.: the two broken line in the red and blue zones.

Comment: I changed the graph in the answer for the correct graph.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question if possible, I can see that this domain is not open, and not bounded, and not connected. Now to decide if it's closed, I know the definition is that a set is called a closed set if it includes all it's boundary points, and it's confusing me since this domain doesn't have boundary from the bottom left or top right and keeps growing, how can I decide?

Comment: Can you decide something about the complement of the given set? Or else: if $\;\left\{ x_n,\,y_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\;$ is a *convergent* sequence in the domain, is its limit inside the domain? You can try to use some arithmetic of limits here.